# Angularjs fa-spinner waiting for http response sometimes hang

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a simple code to show some visual when an api call is still in progress. As follows:

```js
class Controller {
  constructor(apiService) {
    this._apiService = apiService;
    this.loadStatus = "";
    this.data = null;
  }

  loadData() {
    this.loadStatus = "loading";
    this._apiService.call()
      .then(res => {
        this.loadStatus = "success";
        this.data = res;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.loadStatus = "failed";
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" ng-if="$ctrl.loadStatus === 'loading'"></span>
<span ng-if="$ctrl.loadStatus === 'failed'">Failed to load!</span>
<p ng-if="$ctrl.loadStatus === 'success'"> {{$ctrl.data}}</p>
```

The api just calls $http and return a promise after processing the http response.

Now my problem is that "SOMETIMES" the spinner just stops rotating and the screen hangs on the loading spinner, although the response happened and the browser loaded the views but they are not visible, I know that the view is placed because when I move with the mouse on the location where the view should be placed I can see the pointer changes according to the view element css properties (like if the view has a link). Now the view becomes visible and the spinner disappear when I click the mouse anywhere. I think when clicking a digest cycle occurs? or something I don't know? Though the `then` of the promise returned by $http should be called in $apply... Does any one know what is wrong here?

Comment: can you explain what exactly happens when you move your mouse? Do you have any added CSS on your page relating to `loadStatus`?

Comment: no, no css to loadstatus, no css to the spans that show spinner other than fontswesome css. When I move my mouse on the empty screen that has the spinner on it not spinning I can see the mouse cursor changing, as if the view is rendered and the elements are causing the cursor to change,  as soon as I click anywhere the view is visible now to and the spinner disappears.

Comment: that's an unusual behaviour that your current code is not capable of replicating, try adding more relevant code (or somehow create a Plunker/JSFiddle with working $http request)

Comment: can this be related to my pc? my browser? having dev tools opened? I have tried it on several projects and they produce the same output "Some of the time" I don't even know what triggers it and what not...

Comment: who knows, but older browsers don't support classes, `ng-if` creates its own scope, controllerAs syntax can play a role here too, maybe `$http` callback needs to be moved in your controller, or use `.then((res)=>{...},(err)=>{...})` syntax

Comment: I use babel for compiling es6, and I use latest chrome version.

Comment: That is really a odd behaviour. You can give ng-switch a shot.